# How to style JavaScript in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a word completer. I styling with Bootstrap but I cannot make any difference in the output.
I use jQuery and JavaScript for the program. 
The results appear in a list. I don't know how I can fix it.

[image: webpage]

Here is my code.

**word_finder.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Autocomplete Sentences</title>

  <!-- Libraries -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



  <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "Apple",
     ...
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme",
      "Türk Hava Kurumu Üniversitesi"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="ui-widget">
    <h1 style="color: purple;"> Word Finder </h1>
    <br>
  <p class=" lead text-primary">Welcome. As you start writing, suggestions will start to appear. </p>
  <label for="tags">Start typing </label>
  <input id="tags" class="form-control" style=" position: center;">
</div>

</body>
<style> ... <style>
</html>
```

Comment: If you controll the list html output add a bootstrap css class and get predefined styling - or set up your own css for ul element inside .ui-widget div

Comment: It's probably a CSS issue, very likely in `/resources/demos/style.css`. When I tested your code it worked and looked fine, but of course I didn't have that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you are using jQuery autocomplete, it provides auto complete tags  after your:

```
  <input id="tags" class="form-control" style=" position: center;">
```

Tags HTML:

```
<ul id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui- 
   autocomplete ui-front" style="display: block;top: 32px;left: 
   50.6875px;width: 170px;">
   <li class="ui-menu-item"></li>
</ul>
```

you ca style ul dropdown by using

any of the class from here

```
ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete ui-front
```

for li use "ui-menu-item" class to style

```
<style>
.ui-autocomplete {
   background-color: red;
}
.ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item {
   color: #FFF;
}
</style>
```